# Foreign table not using index

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-fdw, query-performance

I have a table on database `temp_db` named `external_objects` and an index on the field `id`, which is an MongoDB id (like 5458d717cd07870859000003). When I explain this select at this database, I got this

```
 explain verbose SELECT origin_id
    from external_objects 
    where id = '5458d717cd07870859000003'  


"Index Only Scan using eoid_lookup_tmp_ix1 on public.external_objects  (cost=0.56..8.57 rows=1 width=16)"
"  Output: origin_id"
"  Index Cond: (external_objects.id = '5458d717cd07870859000003'::text)"
```

I connected this table to another database, via postgres_fdw with

```
-- Creating external_objects table
CREATE FOREIGN TABLE external_objects_mosql
(
  id text NOT NULL,
  created_at date,
  origin_id text,
  _extra_props text
) SERVER mosql_data  OPTIONS (table_name 'external_objects', schema_name 'public');
```

on the staging server, but when I try explain the same query on this foreign table, I see this

```
 explain verbose SELECT external_objects_mosql.origin_id
    from external_objects_mosql 
    where external_objects_mosql.id = '5458d717cd07870859000003'


"Foreign Scan on public.external_objects_mosql  (cost=100.00..147085.60 rows=1 width=16)"
"  Output: origin_id"
"  Remote SQL: SELECT origin_id FROM public.external_objects WHERE ((id = '5458d717cd07870859000003'::text))"
```

Seems like that when using postgres_fdw, I'm unable to use indexes, and this is costing me too much time. is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Here you see a foreign scan - I think it does not tell you if it uses an index or not.  I would expect it does and you lose the time on network latency or elsewhere.  Please add the output of `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` for both queries.

Comment: @dezso right away: http://pastebin.com/NbDP6yE7

Comment: You can edit your question with those.  Anyway, there is only a half millisecond difference between the two - is there a reason (say, a huge dataset in the future) why you are worried about it?

Comment: I have 3 millions records in this origin table, and when it comes to create this table on staging with the records of origin table, it takes too much time (and this table will grow soon)

Comment: I think that is a different issue.  But how often do you need to create this foreign table?  Isn't it a one-time operation?

Comment: yes, one time operation